# How to pop up a simple div where clicking happens with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, popup

Like what you see when modifying status on the left page in gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd say away from a plugin for this. I posted an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-simple-pop-up-using-jquery). Give it a shot - you'll have a lot of control and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of jQuery pop-up plug-ins around the net, [here](http://www.dvq.co.nz/web-design/create-a-jquery-popup-bubble-effect/) is a simple one.

Enjoy.