# Pop up Modal Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-dialog

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945216/pop-up-form-on-button-click) post I've been able to implement a dialog box that appears once the form is loaded. I would however like to change this so that the user clicks a button for the dialog to appear.

I've followed the guidance provided, and removed this line `$("#divdeps").dialog('open');` from the Javascript function as instructed, and added it to the 'onclick' event of my button i.e.

```
<button type="button" value="Upload" onclick="$('#divdeps').dialog('open');">Upload</button>
```

so my code is now:

```
<div id="divdeps" style="display: none">This is my div</div>
<button type="button" value="Upload" onclick="$('#divdeps').dialog('open');">Upload</button>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divdeps").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: 'slide',
    resizable: false,
    position: 'center',
    stack: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    modal: true
  });

 // $("#divdeps").dialog('open');
});

</script>
```

However, I can't get this to work on the 'onclick' event of the button. I've been through the instructions quite a few times now and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: Your button code has mismatched quotes and is not properly closed. `<button value="Upload" onclick="$('#divdeps').dialog('open');"></button>`. This should work, however there are different ways to implement this as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @Virendra - I hope you don't mind me adding your comment to my answer +1 to your old answer as thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with the `click` function of jQuery instead of that dom level 0 handler:

```
$("#divdeps + button").click(function() { $("#divdeps").dialog('open'); });
```

Or of course you can give this button an id and do

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() { $("#divdeps").dialog('open'); });
```

Either of those sections of code would go in your `document.ready` handler.

---

Per Virendra's comment, your original button tag was wrong—you were missing a closing tag, and have mismatched quotes:

```
<button value="Upload" onclick="$("#divdeps").dialog('open');"</button>
```

should have been

```
<button value="Upload" onclick="$('#divdeps').dialog('open');"> </button>
```

Comment: The button isn't inside the `<div>`

Comment: @Wex - I know - OP's indentation threw me off - it's fixed

Comment: Still broken, the quotes are mismatched.

Comment: @Virendra - thanks.  I was searching and searching for the mismatched quotes but couldn't find it.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#divdeps").dialog('open');` that you commented out, try:

```
$("button#give_it_some_id").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divdeps").dialog('open');
})
```

Comment: If it's a button that isn't in a form, is `e.preventDefault()` absolutely necessary?

Comment: All, many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. I've gone for the solution provided by @Virendra. Once again thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its working in my application.

```
PopUpWindow = function (titles, message, redirectURL) {
        document.getElementById('window').innerHTML = message;
        $("#window").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 180,
            title: titles,
            width: 500,
            modal: false,
            open: function () {
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').show();
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close.ui-corner-all').hide();
            },
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    if (redirectURL) {
                        window.location = redirectURL;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

div tag

```
  <div id="window" style="display: none;width:190px">
```

Let me know if you have any problem here.