# form submit via popup

Tags: jquery

I have made a form. I want to open a inline popup on submit and make a text box in the popup that is compulsory to be filled and then in the popup when the user submits a form, the form then gets submitted via popup and page gets refreshed.

I am not able to show alert box in the popup and submit the form via popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".variousz").trigger('click');

  });

$(".variousz").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    afterClose: function(){
         $('#formsubmit').submit();
        }

});
$("form").submit(function() {
 if ($('#accept').val() == 'ACCEPT'){ } else { $("span").text("Query is Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
 return false; }
});
});
</script>
<body>

    <div id="inline" style="display:none;width:500px;">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>     
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="accept" id="accept" value=""><span></span>

        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
    </div>  
    <div class="tab_container">
            <a style="display:none;" class="variousz" href="#inline">Inline</a>

            <form method="GET" action="test.html" id="formsubmit" onsubmit="test.html" >
            <input type="text" name="aaa">
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"> 
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: **Good luck with it!** How can we help you with it???

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several popup plugins over here.
http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/
And implement them with your form.

 [This old example is a good one too](http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/popupjquery/)
And all the [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox),[fancybox](http://fancybox.net) [Other light box alternatives](http://www.tecdiary.com/blog/web-designing/top-10-css3-lightbox-alternatives.html)
[like these might be handful](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/lightbox).

And there is an other [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945216/pop-up-form-on-button-click) exactly same as this.
Thank you