# how to make a javascript covered slideup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

When you first click the answer text area, it will pop up a message box

```
Your Answer
Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!

Please make sure you answer the question; this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Provide details and share your research. Avoid statements based solely on opinion; 
only make statements you can back up with an appropriate reference, or 
personal experiences.
```

[image]

I am struggling to implement this in my own system. I have checked the [jQuery slideUp function](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), but it slides the text message box **down** not up.

Does any one know how to implement it?

I am assuming that it uses JavaScript animation.

Comment: There is a description of how to do popups with jquery here  [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Comment: There is a description of how to do popups [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Comment: Do you have any relevant code for this question?

Comment: no , i just want know is there any function to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .div1 {
      width:400px;
      height:100px;
      border: 1px solid #777777;
      }
      .div2 {
      width:400px;
      height:100px;
      border: 1px solid #777777;
      overflow:hidden;
      }
      .help {
      background-color:#fefae2;
      border: 1px solid #f3eed5;
      width:400px;
      height:100px;
      margin-top:100px;
      }
      .info-ok{
      font-size: 13px;
      color:#1087a4;
      float:right;
      margin-top:5px;
      margin-right:5px;
      }
      .info-head{
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top:15px;
      margin-right:5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function popdown(){
    $(".help").animate({
    marginTop:"100px",
    }, 1000 );
    }
    function popup(){
    $(".help").animate({
    marginTop:"0px",
    }, 1000 );
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div class="div1">a</div>
    <div class="div2">
      <div class="help">
    <a class="info-ok" onclick="popdown()">ok</a>
    <p class="info-head">您的答案</p>
    <p>感谢您对StackPointer做的贡献</p>
    <p>请确保您回答这个问题,这是一个问答网站，而不是一个论坛</p>
    <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">c</div>
    <textarea onclick="popup()"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/EXyxb/12/) it?
I think you want to use .slideToggle()

HTML

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="msg">
     谢谢你!!
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".msg").slideToggle();
    $("textarea").focus(function(){
        $(".msg").slideToggle();
    });
    $("textarea").blur(function(){
        $(".msg").slideToggle();
    });
```

What do you want to appear and when?

Comment: ye, but if you put the textarea bellow the div , when it click the textarea , the textarea will lide down , i need the textarea don't move , just div to slide up

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/EXyxb/5/ is just extra css, i'll post an update to my jsfiddle, but it will just be a matter of using `position:absolute` if you show me an example of what you want it to look like i could help more... 我不知道您想要什么

Comment: I don't know where the popup thing from clicking on a textarea is (that you want to duplicate). Maybe take a screenshot?

Comment: There are a lot of options on how to display a message; you should evaluate jQuery UI Dialog and jqModel.  你们都中国人吗？

Comment: i have add the image , 我是中国人，呵呵。

Comment: it all depends on your specific desires for the styles http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/EXyxb/11/ should help you get started with anything tricky, and then u can just edit it (i don't know how much padding around it etc. you want) 我不中国人，可是在清华读书了……

Comment: actually, the examples I gave were a little bad... you should use http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/EXyxb/12/ (I changed `slideToggle()` to `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`) 我原来是美国人，现在在美国工作你用人人或QQ吗？

Comment: i think it is use javascript animation.not slide

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your textarea is like this

```
<textarea id='answer'></textarea>
```

SO you can use

```
$('textarea#answer').bind('click', function() {alert('Thanks')})
```

Comment: the alert('Thanks') will just popup a windows , i don't want thant

Comment: You can write the required code in function(). I mean first you can take a hidden div, then you can show it using $('div#message').show('fast'). It depends on your imagination and requirement, but this is the basic guidance