# Close popup box before opening new one

Tags: jquery

So I came across this thread and it works very well - [How to generate a simple popup using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery). However, I have a second link and I've changed the class name and everything. Works fine but there are two issues.

1 - If I click on one link and then decide to click on the other link, it displays the second div on top of the first one. If I click "Cancel," I end up having to close BOTH divs in succession. Not a big deal but I'm trying to make it idiot proof.

2 - If I click on "Add Room" and then happen to click on it again, then I can't click the "Cancel" button to hide the div overlay. I could display the div over the link so the user can't click it again, but it doesn't look as clean.

Here's the code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#add_room").live('click', function(event) {                    
        $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append('<div class="messagepop pop"><form method="post" action="/room/add"><label for="room">Room Name</label><div class="field_span"><input type="text" size="10" class="text" name="location_name" id="room" /></div><div class="buttonrow_popup"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="commit" class="submit small" id="room_submit"/><a class="close" style="margin-top:6px;float: right;border:0">Cancel</a></div></form></div>');
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#room").focus();
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(".close").live('click', function() {
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#add_room").removeClass("selected");
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#add_item").live('click', function(event) {          
        $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append('<div class="messagepop pop1"><form method="post" action="/room/add"><label for="item">Item Name</label><div class="field_span"><input type="text" size="10" class="text" name="item_name" id="item" /></div><div class="buttonrow_popup"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="commit" class="submit small" id="room_submit"/><a class="close1" style="margin-top:6px;float: right;border:0">Cancel</a></div></form></div>');
        $(".pop1").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#item").focus();
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(".close1").live('click', function() {
        $(".pop1").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
            $("#add_room").removeClass("selected");
        });
        return false;
    });

});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch, that seems like a lot of code.  In the same link you posted in your question is another answer that mentions using [jQuery UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery/1328731#1328731) instead.  I'd highly recommend using that instead, as it is by far easier to use.

Comment: interesting, i'll take a look. I've seen various tutorials and I assume the dialog box can be skinned w/ CSS.

Comment: There is a `jQuery-ui.css` you can download and change as needed.