# Form open in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a master page and take the menu on the master page.

```
<li>
   <a href="#">Edit</a>
   <ul>
      <li>
           <a href="#" id="A2" runat="server" onclick="fnEditState()">Edit State</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Now I want that Each form open in new tab with closing button. Main purpose is that I could multiple form open on the same time and same window.
Please help me

Comment: for your a tag use target as blank `<a href="#" id="A2" target="_blank" runat="server" onclick="fnEditState()">Edit State</a>` What does your javascript function `fnEditState()`  do??

Comment: function fnEditState() {

            window.open("View/updateState.aspx", "", "status=2,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=800,height=300");


        }                                                                    right now open in new window.

Comment: applied `target="_blank"` to your anchor tag? which browser u are using? to open a new window in a tab is your browser setting. nothing to do with your `target="_blank"` this attribute will open the window in new window, **depending on your browser setting it will open in tab, or new window.**

Comment: I want to take a tab panel on the master page. and all form open in new tab not in new window pls help me

Comment: Instead of creating new window create new `<div>` elements using JavaScript. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery) for some pointers and examples.

Comment: you are saying you want to create a new tab on your tab panel control placed on master page, and open your page there?? Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a new tab to open when you click "Edit State" instead of a popup window?

In that case you could just do:

```
<a href="View/updateState.aspx" id="A2" runat="server" target="_blank">Edit State</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer to open a tab and not new window on click of the link, through window.open

you can just add the below to parameters in your window.open method

modal=yes,
alwaysRaised=yes

```
function fnEditState() {
window.open("View/updateState.aspx", "","status=2, scrollbars=1,resizable=1, width=800,  height=300, modal=yes, alwaysRaised=yes"); 
}
```