# jquery ui popup MVC 3 not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application (my first) and running into some trouble with jQuery, as I've never used it before. I'm trying to open up details for a particular search result in a modal dialog.

relevant razor code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.claims)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.CLAIMMASTID.Substring(Math.Max(0,item.CLAIMMASTID.Length-1)), "ClaimDetail", new {@id=item.CLAIMMASTID}, new {@class="ClaimsDetail"})</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And the controller has that set up to display a partial view:

```
public ActionResult ClaimDetail()
    {
        return PartialView("_ClaimDetail");
    }
```

All good so far, yes? That's what I think. So my jQuery script looks as such, and it's where I think the problem lies:

```
$(function () {
    $('#ClaimsDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true
    });
    $('.ClaimsDetail').live("click", function () {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(target, function (result) {
            ('#ClaimsDialog').html(result);
            ('#ClaimsDialog').dialog({
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery might help

Comment: Debug the code in VS2010 and see what it says when it reaches the relevant line. Enable debugging in IE (tools->internet options->advanced, uncheck 'disable script debugging'), run the solution and open the web-page in IE. I had to do that today when calling the valid() method did nothing, and turned out I was missing a script reference. Also as DanielB said, live() is deprecated since 1.43 and by default MVC3 uses atleast version 1.5 (1.8 is the jQuery UI version, not jQuery!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
 $.get(target, function (result) {
        ('#ClaimsDialog').html(result);
        ('#ClaimsDialog').dialog({
        });
    });
```

with

```
  $.get(target, function (result) {
        $('#ClaimsDialog').html(result).dialog('open');
    });
```

Comment: That's still not doing anything. Let me take a look at what firebug is telling me

Comment: What happens? Is the ajax call executed or not? Which version of jquery you are using? `live()` is deprecated since 1.4.3.

Comment: The call is executed, according to firebug. And right click "open in new tab/window" both work. 

1.8.11

Comment: then you have to debug the javascript step by step. to few information to give better hints.