# Pop up window display in JSP and struts2 framework

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am trying to implement a pop up displaying the description of the option in the list is selected in jsp.I am using struts2 framework.
Kindly help.

Comment: your question is not very much clear.what value you want to show in pop-up?

Comment: Display the description should display in the pop-up for the options selected in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to use jQuery core or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) API through which you can use advanced and themeable widgets to build interactive web applications.

EDIT:

SO Thread - [How to generate a simple popup using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery)

Comment: can you please tell the exact widget which will be applicable for this  functionality?

Comment: @Soham Did you look at the widgets? Did you see any that look like dialogs?

Comment: Yes I had seen the dialogs widget.Probably it may help to implement.Thanks!!.