# open links in new window from sub window or Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, firefox

I need your quick help.

In my web site I have a list of clients with links to their user details.

I used

```
window.open();return false;
```

and this opens each profile in new window.

1. now in the new opening window I have link, which I want to open in another new window/

I tried

```
window.opener.open();return false;
```

but it opened in this same window.

How can it be opened in another new window(FF,explorer)??.

1. I want also to use the above code with **Ajax**, in my search page.
   The problem is, that it also not opening the new window because the link located in the Ajax. how can i open links from Ajax in new window??

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I am unable to follow you. you have a window with a link that opens a new window and from it you would like to open a new window. why not just use window.open on that new window?

Comment: I think you should rethink those wndow open strategies. Opening a window from a window, then in that one opening another one on click, is not a too good experience. I think you should do both in the first window, using some javascript to reveal new divs (or whatever) with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Providing height and width to open. this will make sure that new window always open as popup.

```
window.open(url, 'name', "height=500,width=700"); return false;
```

Comment: I tried it. when I click the link in this new window it redirects, not opens in new window

Comment: For that you have to use return false.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can access window.parent from your window object and call a function that will open another window

Answer (score 0):

Use Window.open() in the opened window.

Answer (score 0):

So you have : (1) Page  with a link -> (2) opens a popup with a link -> (3) opens another popup

Every link which has to open a popup will call the javascript function *window.open*. As @Sushil pointed out, if the new window has to look like a regular popup, set width and height to it.

If you want to implement the popups using AJax, use jQuery. [Here is a very good example for a simple popup implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery)

Comment: Thank you!  when I click on the link in the **new** window(2) it redirects, not open the (3) in new window. Maybe it impossible.