# Looking for jQuery tooltip plugin which supports inline popup like overLib

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, mouseover

I'll start with the code

```
<form name='form 1' action='$action'>
input tags
<table>
some tr tags along with td tags
and after some lines in the same table under a td tag
<td>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return overlib('<FORM name=\'form 2\' action=\'$action\'>....code for this form.....</FORM>');">XYZ</a>
</td>
....
....
</table>
</form>
```

So as you can see I have used [overLib](http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/) to create a inline popup. This returns a form when you click on "XYZ". It works fine.

Now I want to use some other jQuery plugin, I tried jQuery Hovercards, jQuery tooltip etc. But the problem which I am facing is that these plugins don't have a popup feature like overLib. They basically use a "hiddendiv" and display it when you hover over "XYZ" (should return form when you hover over XYZ) but it doesn't return a form, why? Because if you notice carefully this `form 2` is inside `form 1` and you know you can't use a `form` inside another `form`. It was working fine in overLib case because it was creating a popup.

Now I'm looking for an overLib alternative which can create a popup so that I can return a form in that popup. Is there any tooltip plugin which has inline popup feature? Or how can I tweak this HTML code to allow form inside form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any related plugin so I created a simple jQuery popup. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329605/257635) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return overlib('<FORM name=\'form 2\' action=\'$action\'>....code for this form.....</FORM>');">XYZ</a>
```

with this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return overlib('\<FORM name=\'form 2\' action=\'$action\'\>....code for this form.....\</FORM\>');">XYZ</a>
```

I have tried it and it worked well.

Comment: I know, it's working fine. I think you didn't read the question completely. OverLib is working fine for me. I need an alternative to overLib which can do the same function (creating inline popup)

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, sorry for the misunderstanding. Here is jtip that I use for my project

Web --> http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/javascript-tooltip-jtip.html
Demo --> http://www.codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/

Comment: Does it has inline popup feature?

Comment: Yes it is. As you can see the code in demo page, jtip get another page to display in popup page where it is more flexible and easy to handle. The different between 2 or more jtip is the id inside <a href"" tag.