# Reducing duplicated code with JQuery function

Tags: jquery

Found a good jquery popup function here:

```
 JAVASCRIPT
 $(function() {
    $("#word1234").live('click', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append('
          <div class="messagepop pop">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
          consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</div>');
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle()
        $("#email").focus();
        return false;
    });
    $(".close").live('click', function() {
        $(".pop").slideFadeToggle();
        $("#contact").removeClass("selected");
        return false;
    });


 HTML
 <a href='/word1234' id='word1234'>Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</a>
```

Is there a more efficient way of invoking this popup?  If I have hundreds of definitions on a page I'd be repeating a lot of code seemingly unnecessarily.

If I were doing this in native JS, I'd just set a onClick function to the href tag,something like

```
 <a href="#" id="word1234" onClick="doPop(this, 'Lorem ipsum, ect.')">Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</a>
```

Is there a similar method of calling a function in JQuery?

**EDIT**
After some debugging, a working version of the updated/fixed script can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/13/  hth.

Comment: instead of an id, which restricts you to a SINGLE dom element, use a class, which can be applied to as many dom elements as you want.

Comment: How do you define the relation between the popup content and the element ?

Comment: In my own popup libraries, one of the ways to add a popup is to have an attribute : `<a bubble="some text">`. It's easy with jQuery to select elements with the attribute : `$('[bubble]')`.

Comment: @MarcB - that may be part of the rewrite, but I'd need some way of identifying the specific element for the removeClass function.

Comment: @dystroy: that makes it invalid html, though. which is why most people abuse css classes to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @acoder: but it's part of the DOM tree. a node in the tree ALWAYS knows where it is. once you're in your onclick, the `this` will most likely point at the element which was clicked, and your "selected" node will be right nextdoor/nearby.

Comment: @MarcB Good point. But you may make it `data-bubble` if it bothers you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn the code into a [jQuery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) like this:

```
$.fn.myPopup = function(popupText){
    var popupHtml = '<div class="messagepop pop">' + popupText + '</div>';
    this.each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){

            // Create the popup
            $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append(popupHtml);

            // Find the close button and attach click handler
            $(this).find(".close").click(
                // Find, hide, then delete the popup
                $(this).closest(".pop").slideFadeToggle().remove();;
            );

        });
        return false;
    });

    return this;
};
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
$("#word1234").myPopup("Lorem Ipsum");
$("#wordABCD").myPopup("Hello World");
```

Comment: The popup text would be identical across all words: "Lorem ipsum".

Comment: I allowed to do this in JQuery?  $("#word1234").myPopup('Lorem ipsump, ect');  if so problem solved.

Comment: Slight problem, the close functionality is broken.  It closes the popup, but a new popup immediately replaces it.  http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/3/

Comment: I've updated the code to simplify it a bit. But tbh, I think the question regarding code re-use is answered and it just requires a bit of debugging.

Comment: Ok thanks - not sure if this is yours or someone elses, but it works.  I'm new to JQuery and could do this with native JS.  Trying to learn something new here and wasn't having much success debugging. 
thanks again.  http://jsfiddle.net/N4QCZ/6/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `live` use `on`, live was deprecated as of 1.7:

You could give your links a popup class and do:

```
$(".popup").on("click", function() {
    // Your code
});
```

That way you can capture all links with the `popup` class and are not binding to 100's of events, i.e:

```
$("#id1").click() { }
$("#id2").click() { }
```

etc.

Comment: This makes sense, but I need the id for removeClass().

Comment: @acoder - you could add a data attribute to the <a> tag: ie: <a data-id="yourid" /> and then use jquery to find the element with the data attribute.

Comment: Could do the same with the word definition? <a class='popup'  data-id="yourid" data-def="Lorem ipsum,ect">Supercali</a>  Is Jquery smart enough to draw the association in the same element?

Comment: @acoder - you could but I wouldn't recommend storing long text in a data attribute.