# Multiple pop up windows with different content in each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I originally found a good jQuery pop-up function I'm using for a website I'm creating. The original post was from here: [Reducing duplicated code with JQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836965/reducing-duplicated-code-with-jquery-function)

Basically what I want to achieve is to have each pop-up box contain different content (such as everything in my .pop1 & .pop2 divs: p and img), so then I can be able to still give it styles through CSS. I also need to make sure the right divs pop-up on their related link.

This is the code I'm working with:

**Jquery**

```
 $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
    });
};

$.fn.myPopup = function(popupText) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var popupHtml = $('<div />', {'class': 'messagepop pop', text: popupText}),
            p         = $('<p />', {style: 'align="right"'}),
            close     = $('<a />', {href: '#', 'class': 'close', text: 'Close'});

        $(this).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append(popupHtml.append(p).append(close));
            $(".pop").slideFadeToggle()
            $("#email").focus();
        });
        close.on('click', function(e) {
            $(".pop").slideFadeToggle();
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        });
    });
};

$("#word1234").myPopup($(".pop"));
$("#wordABCD").myPopup($(".pop2"));
```

And the **HTML**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" id="word1234">Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="wordABCD">Foo</a></li>

<div class="messagepop pop">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Sugimoris025.png" width="100px" />
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum
  </p>  
</div>

<div class="messagepop pop2">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg" width="100px" />
  <p>
  Hello World
  </p>  
</div>
```

Here is the code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6rcr1d2v/

I'm a beginner at jQuery, so if anyone could help me fix and explain as easiest as possible how this can be done I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

**Edit:** Someone did help with getting the boxes to pop up. Now I need help getting the pop-up boxes to not come out at the same time. They need to pop-up separately with their related link (class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you had a few syntax errors. You are not surrounding the pop and pop2 selectors in quotations.

The correct way to find a jQuery element is

`$(".className")`

Notice quotations around the class selector.

```js
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
    });
};

$.fn.myPopup = function(popupText) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var popupHtml = $('<div />', {'class': 'messagepop pop', text: popupText}),
            p         = $('<p />', {style: 'align="right"'}),
            close     = $('<a />', {href: '#', 'class': 'close', text: 'Close'});
        
        $(this).on('click', function(){
            $(this).addClass("selected").parent().append(popupHtml.append(p).append(close));
            $(popupText).slideFadeToggle()
            $("#email").focus();
        });
        close.on('click', function(e) {
            $(popupText).slideFadeToggle();
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        });
    });
};

$("#word1234").myPopup($(".pop"));
$("#wordABCD").myPopup($(".pop2"));
```

```css
a.selected {
  z-index:100;
}

.messagepop {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 25px 25px 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

.messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" id="word1234">Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="wordABCD">Foo</a></li>

<div class="messagepop pop">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Sugimoris025.png" width="100px" />
  <p>
  Lorem Ipsum
  </p>  
</div>

<div class="messagepop pop2">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000822867536/3f5a00acf72df93528b6bb7cd0a4fd0c.jpeg" width="100px" />
  <p>
  Hello World
  </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I did miss those quotation marks. The boxes do work now. Now it's just the issue of not having both boxes open at the same time. I need them to open separately when being clicked on the href.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please specify.

Comment: I have two boxes: 

$("#word1234").myPopup($(".pop"));
$("#wordABCD").myPopup($(".pop2"));

These are both appearing at the same time as a click on any of the a href links. I need a one box to appear when I click on the related a href link (example: class=".pop2" box will pop up when I click on a href id="#wordABCD").

Comment: Does this work better? I changed it so that in the popup function, when you slideFadeToggle, it toggles the element passed into the function.