# Simple popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement the code found in the best answer to the following question:
[How to generate a simple popup using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery/1329605#1329605)

Why will the following page of code below not work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.selected {
          background-color:#1F75CC;
          color:white;
          z-index:100;
        }
        .messagepop {
          background-color:#FFFFFF;
          border:1px solid #999999;
          cursor:default;
          display:none;
          margin-top: 15px;
          position:absolute;
          text-align:left;
          width:394px;
          z-index:50;
          padding: 25px 25px 20px;
        }
        label {
          display: block;
          margin-bottom: 3px;
          padding-left: 15px;
          text-indent: -15px;
        }
        .messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
          margin: 8px 0;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
        }       
    </style>

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <script>
        function deselect() {
            $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
                $("#contact").removeClass("selected");
            });    
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#contact").live('click', function() {
                if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                    deselect();               
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                    $(".pop").slideFadeToggle(function() { 
                        $("#email").focus();
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });

            $(".close").live('click', function() {
                deselect();
                return false;
            });
        });

        $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
            return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, "fast", easing, callback);
        };
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="messagepop pop">
        <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages">
            <p><label for="email">Your email or name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" /></p>
            <p><label for="body">Message</label><textarea rows="6" name="body" id="body" cols="35"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <a href="/contact" id="contact">Contact Us</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no Javascript code in that markup. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Now we know what's going on: jQuery 1.9.1 does not support `live()`. Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frederic Hamidi commented first, but thought of including it as my answer since he didn't answer it.

Saw your edit. You are including jquery 1.9.1 where `.live()` is *removed*.

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7. It was *removed* in 1.9.