# Easing parameter in jQuery function automatically identified?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The answer to [How to generate a simple popup using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery) presents the following short jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SRw67/. In the jsFiddle you find:

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}
```

where the function **slideFadeToggle** is defined as:

```
$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

In the jQuery documentation I found:

> **easing** A string indicating which easing function to use for the
>   transition.

The function slideFadeToggle has 2 parameters but in the code only a function is passed. Does jQuery automatically identify that the parameter is a function and thus skips the easing parameter and passes the function as the callback? Or why is this working, when obviously the easing parameter is missing?

Further, why is the author using **$.fn.slideFadeToggle =..**?

I found here [What does jQuery.fn mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean/4083362) that this is a shortcut for **$.prototype.slideFadeToggle** but it does not make any sense to me. Why is this useful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does jQuery automatically identify that the parameter is a function
>   and thus skips the easing parameter and passes the function as the
>   callback?

Yes, that's exactly what happens.

You can see by reading the jQuery source that `animate` is not very particular about having both formal arguments passed to it. In the current version this is done indirectly: those arguments are used to [construct an options object by calling `jQuery.Speed`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e04e246552c27e872bbf4ae00b55def02b197189/src/effects.js#L487-L489), which in turn [inspects the types of its arguments](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e04e246552c27e872bbf4ae00b55def02b197189/src/effects.js#L439-L445) to determine which one corresponds to what (`undefined` is also implicitly handled by the boolean checks).

The same behavior is also seen on lots of other jQuery methods; e.g. the ubiquitous `on` recognizes four arguments, of which the second and third are optional.

Comment: Does it mean that in the function **slideFadeToggle** has callback as none and the function is saved in **easing**, and then I call animate with **animat(..'fast',function(..),none)** and the animate function detects autmatically that a function is passed? Thus, the word **easing** is not a special keyword or anything and I could rewrite all oocurences wth **easing* into **earing** for example?

Comment: @Adam yes and yes. "easing" is just the name of the formal parameter of the function. You could call it whatever you want and nothing at all would change. The only things that matter are number and order of arguments (as always) plus the special logic that's embedded in jQuery.

Comment: If I would only pass a string as first optional paramenter, then the method animate would probably think its duration, right? Even if I pass "swing"?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you'll see that the `easing` argument is optional. The specification is:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

The way it determines if you provided this argument is by checking the datatype of the third argument -- if it's a string, it's `easing`, but if it's a function it means you left out the `easing` argument (so it will use the default), and this is the `complete` argument. Many jQuery methods work like this; as long as the types of the optional arguments are all different, it can figure out which ones you left out.

Since `slideFadeToggle()` simply passes on its arguments, you automatically get the same ability to leave out `easing`.

Answer (score 0):

The default `easing` is `"swing"` , see [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)