# How to use "Term of Use" in Popup

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to customize the `term of use` in popup, when a user login for first time that page should appear in popup.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: @Akash What are the options that you have explored to achieve the same?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I haven't got any thing related to my query.

Comment: Could you plz provide exact flow scenario as to what is required and the need for the same?

Comment: I want to customize the "term of use" page, when a user log into the portal for the first time, that "term of use" message should appear in pop up

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal you found something?

Comment: @Akash I get you point but then,there must be some screen needed in the background or something,after you login,on which the pop up should appear?As a more practical approach,the Terms of use or User Agreement should usually be a part of Account creation form or if not,you can check for using it as an expandable division,when user first logs in!

Comment: @Akash It would be very nice to have more clarity behind reasoning on why and how exactly it needs to be used

Answer (score 4):

To set the terms of use you will need to do 2 things.

First you'll need to create a Web Content Article.

1. Go to the Control Panel.
2. Select "Web Content".
3. Then Add > "Basic Content".
4. Enter in your desired Terms of Use language.
5. Write down the ID and the Group ID you've created the content.

Note: The ID is available when you're viewing the content's page but the group ID is less obvious. To find the group ID, look at the URL, and find the parameter `doAsGroupId`. Its value is the group ID you've created the article for.

Secondly, you'll need to configure your portal to load this Web Content article.

1. From the file system, navigate to your Liferay Portal installation.
2. From there find the `portal.properties` file. If you're using Tomcat, it will be located in `webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes`.
3. Here add a file named `portlet-ext.properties`, if it does not already exist.
4. Add the following keys with the values you previously wrote down.

   ```
   terms.of.use.journal.article.group.id=
   terms.of.use.journal.article.id=
   ```

Restart your server and the portal should now display the Terms of Use form the Web Content article.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my question was how i can display that term of use page in a popup?

Answer (score 2):

Use bootstrap modal with javascript for popup

**JavaScript Code:** (write this code inside script tag)

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {  
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

**HTML Code:** (make sure that **Javascript Code** and **HTML Code** should be in same tab)

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ... **(Write your content here)**
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use links in place of button.

Be sure to add ***role="dialog"*** and ***aria-labelledby="..."***, referencing the modal title, to ***.modal***, and ***role="document"*** to the ***.modal-dialog*** itself.

Additionally, you may give a description of your modal dialog with ***aria-describedby*** on ***.modal***.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of modal dialog in bootstrap through which u can achieve what you want.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
$('#newModal').modal('show');
});
```

Don't forget to add this style sheets import in your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Your html file should have the following code

```
<div class="container">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <!Your Heading-->
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Your text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">I Agree</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply go

[How to generate a simple popup using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery)

or

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

For your solution

Or

STYLESHEET

```
    a.selected {
  background-color:#1F75CC;
  color:white;
  z-index:100;
}

.messagepop {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #999999;
  cursor:default;
  display:none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:394px;
  z-index:50;
  padding: 25px 25px 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

.messagepop p, .messagepop.div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   function deselect(e) {
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
        e.removeClass('selected');
      });    
    }

$(function() {
  $('#contact').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="messagepop pop">
    <form method="post" id="new_message" action="/messages">
        <p><label for="email">Your email or name</label><input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email" /></p>
        <p><label for="body">Message</label><textarea rows="6" name="body" id="body" cols="35"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="commit" id="message_submit"/> or <a class="close" href="/">Cancel</a></p>
    </form>
</div>
```