# Bootstrap Popover: Can't set a Margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tried everything .. this just does not budge. This forum post is my last resort on this one. Its been 3 days messing around with a plethora of CSS setting combinations, checking JS for issues and just generally losing my hair.

Please help me with this .. I really dont want to have to give up this whole project because of one stupid line of code somewhere.

**Problem**: The popover box loads flush to the top of the screen, i've tried adding margins to every single container I can both in the bootstrap.css and removing/adding div elements to help resolve this .. and nothing !

**HTML**:

```html
<a href="#" type="submit" name="login" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" data-target="#login-popover" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="float: right; text-decoration: none;"></a>

<div id="login-popover" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myPopoverLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="loginpopover-container">
  <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
  <br>
  <form method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginpopover-submit" value="Login">
  </form>
  <div class="login-help"> <a href="#">Register</a><a href="#" style="float: right">Forgot Password</a> </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"> <?php echo $usernameErr; ?> <?php echo $passwordErr; ?> </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**LOGINBOX.CSS**:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

/****** LOGIN POPOVER ******/
.loginpopover-container {
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto;

}

.loginpopover-container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.loginpopover-container input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.loginpopover-container input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  /* border-radius: 2px; */
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.loginpopover-container input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.login-popover {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 36px;
/* border-radius: 3px; */
/* -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; */
}

.loginpopover-submit {
  /* border: 1px solid #3079ed; */
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 17px 0px;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#4787ed)); */
}

.loginpopover-submit:hover {
  /* border: 1px solid #2f5bb7; */
  border: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  background-color: #357ae8;
  /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,   from(#4d90fe), to(#357ae8)); */
}

.loginpopover-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity ease 0.5s;
} 

.login-help{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script>
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function () {
        var targetId = $(this).attr('data-target');
        return $(targetId).html();
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Just to say in my defense, the reason I am so annoyed is because I do everything possible on my end, so I dont have to push this to you guys. I exhaust every possible reason I can - this process however, seriously tests my patience.

Anyway, any help as always is appreciated. (sad whale face -_____-)

Comment: check this link. may be this will help you [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1329605/6572922)

Comment: Your popover is going to appear next to the link for login.  So it will appear just next to the login link. I positioned the link in the middle of the screen and it appeared next to the link in the middle of the screen.

Comment: I'd like to help, but the problem is a little unclear. Partly because I can't see the current situation and the desired situation. Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?