# newbie: how to add jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying the jquery alert example on this webpage: http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-demo/jquery-demo.php?ex=8.0_1.  I'm new to using jquery and I can't figure out how to get the dependencies listed in the head section:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Here is the full file, but probably not needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Examples of using jQuery Alerts</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!-- Example script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#basic_button").click( function() {
jAlert('Example of a basic alert box in jquery', 'jquery basic alert box');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<input id="basic_button" type="button" value="Show Basic Alert" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess would be you're not following the documentation closely enough. (neither is the person who wrote said tutorial)

Comment: Almost definitely right ... when all else fails, read the instructions.  Please enlighten me to where said documentation exists or how to resolve my problem ;)

Comment: Are you just copying and pasting? If you're doing that, you're probably having issues with the dependencies not being found because the browser is making a request for a resource that won't exist or won't be served. Look into using a CDN if that's the case

Comment: well, it appears as though this is a custom plugin called jAlerts, not the one that has documentation. http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-demo/jquery.alerts.js probably not a very good tutorial to follow.

Comment: MIght be this: https://github.com/aurels/jquery.alerts

Comment: You have already helped me.  I thought this was a standard plugin to be dereferenced by a standard jquery tool (like grunt, bower, etc).  I may reconsider using this code since it appears not to be mainstream, ie, well tested.

Comment: Don't just blindly copy code from tutorials as the paths to certain files may be different. You'll have to update those according to how your project is set up.

Answer (score 1):

Google hosts a CDN. To make sure JQuery's libary is loaded add this into the `<head>` tags

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are trying this on a local machine then you can download jquery [here](https://jquery.com/download/) and set it up in the `<head>` as this:

```
<script src="path_to_jquery" ></script>
```

Comment: I've updated my question.  I know where to get jquery; it's the plugins that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the dependencies here:

http://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-demo.

Answer (score 0):

This serves my purposes much better than the tutorial in this question: [How to generate a simple popup using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery)