# Rails- customize view of confirm dialog box before delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

To delete a record in rails I am using this code

```
<%= link_to "close #{user.name}'s light", light_path(id: light), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

result of which, I get dialog box like this [image]

But I wants this dialog box to look like this
[image]

Is there any way to customize the default view of confirm dialog box?

Comment: You cannot actually chenge default look and behaviour of alert or confirm box. You need to use custom jquery plugins

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Do you have any suggestion of custom jquery plugins to use?

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery) can point you in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of bootstrap modal dialog box, like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4

 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure about closing Ellen's lightbox..
        <%= link_to "Yes", light_path(id: light), method: :delete %>/
        <%= link_to "No", "javascript:void(0)",'data-dismiss': "modal" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And change your initial link to:

```
<%= link_to "close #{user.name}'s light", "javascript:void(0)", 'data-target': "#myModal", 'data-toggle': "modal" %>
```

I hope this might be helpful to you.

Comment: @AmulyaTanksale If you have find my answer helpful you may also upvote it. I am glad to be helpful :)