# mysql popup forgot password

Tags: php, mysql, popup

I have a form forgot password that confirms if the user exists and send a email with a link for password reset, it works fine but i do like that message "email was been sent..." should appear in a popup instead on the same page.

I tried this but does not works:

response.php

```
var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value();
$.get( "validation.php?email="  function( response ) {
    // console.log( response ); // server response
    response = response.trim();
    if(response == 1){
        alert("Email sent....");
    } else{
        alert(response);
        return false;
    }
});
```

}`

Form:

```
<form class="register" id="email" action="forgot.php" method="post" onSubmit="checkAll();">
```

mysql

````
if ($result=="") { $result = "Email has been sent"; }
  echo "<div>$result</div>";
}
?>```
````

Comment: So basically you want the message to be shown in a popup! If you want to do so then just inlcude the code for the pop-up inside the if statement. You may check this question for popup... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328723/how-to-generate-a-simple-popup-using-jquery

Comment: thanks for the reply but inside the if statement always break the whole code and the page does not loads.

Comment: In that case you made some error in including it, you need to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted all and now it works i let here the solution in a hope that can helps someone else:

```
function alert(){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('Email has been sent - Please click on the link in the email to confirm.');";
  echo "</script>";
  }
  
  


 
    if ($result=="") { $result = alert(); }
    }

?>
```